# How to reference an ActiveX ComboBox as an object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to programatically add items to an ActiveX ComboBox.

How do I reference the ComboBox to perform a `.additem` to it.
I tried:

```
Dim lstSubsB As ComboBox
Set lstSubsB = ws.ListObjects("lstSubs") ' - << Error occurs here
```

but it gives a 'Subscript out of Range' error.  The combobox, is named 'lstSubs'.

In addition to the solutions provided, I found that the below also works.

```
 Set lstSubsB = Me.lstSubs
 With lstSubsB
    For x = arrLower To arrUpper
       lstSubs.AddItem arrSubs(x)
    Next x
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objX As Object

Set objX = ws.OLEObjects("lstSubs")
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found an alternative solution (edited description)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I just figured it out and thought I'd save some time for the next person.  The property you want is "Object", which in this case is a ComboBox type.  I'm sure Object type works as well, but strong typing helps with code complete.

```
' This snippet adds sheet names to a combobox
Dim lstSubsB as ComboBox
Dim Sht As Variant

' The Object property in this case returns a typed ComboBox
Set lstSubsB = ws.OLEObjects("lstSubs").Object

lstSubsB.Clear

For Each Sht In Worksheets
    lstSubsB.AddItem Sht.Name
Next
```